# Is it possible to get delta or notification for appRoleAssignments in MS Graph - Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We are currently writing a .net core application and we are using the MS Graph SDK to get users, servicePrincipals and their appRoleAssignments.

Because we are caching the data we are using the delta endpoints of Users and Serviceprincipals to sync our data.

Is there a preferred way to sync the appRoleAssignments?

Or is there a delta endpoint for appRoleAssignments?

Or can we get notifications when an appRole is assigned to a users?

Thanks in advance

Currently we are getting the appRoleAssignments on every request from MSGraph, but this results in a lot of calls.

Comment: Probably, but the MsGraph SDK does not have a reference for "_graphServiceClient.ServicePrincipals["test"].AppRoleAssignments.Delta". 
And if this will work, we still have to execute this request for every user and this will result in a lot of calls.

I guess there is no option for getting the delta of appRoleAssignments objects itself?

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

```
string graphApiEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0";
string deltaToken = "{your-delta-token}";

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

string requestUrl = $"{graphApiEndpoint}/servicePrincipals/{servicePrincipalId}/appRoleAssignments/delta?$deltatoken={deltaToken}";

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(requestUrl);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // Process the response content to get the delta changes
    string nextDeltaToken = response.Headers.GetValues("@odata.deltaLink").FirstOrDefault();
    // Use the nextDeltaToken to retrieve the next set of changes
}
else
{
    // Handle the error response
    string errorContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the MsGraph SDK does not have a reference for "_graphServiceClient.ServicePrincipals["test"].AppRoleAssignments.Delta". And if this will work, we still have to execute this request for every user and this will result in a lot of calls. I guess there is no option for getting the delta of appRoleAssignments objects itself?